# Trouble after deleting .mdf according to official article

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

While deleting an `.mdf` according to [this article](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#goog), I completed all the steps successfully. But, after deleting `.mdf` according to this step:

> From Solution Explorer, click the Show All Files icon, then right
>   click Add_Data\aspnet-MvcAuth-.mdf and click Delete.

when I typed `Enable-Migrations` into the PM-console, I got the message:

> Migrations have already been enabled in project 'ContactManager'. To
>   overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force
>   parameter.

After this I launched it in Internet Explorer. There was no form to register 
with birthday. I made all the steps according to the article.

Comment: Have you trying to re-create DB using Code First Migrations? Remove all existing migrations in Migrations directory right after deleting MDF file, then execute `Add-Migration InitialCreate` and `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, I tried to type: "Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force" there was successfull. Then I typed: "Add-Migration Initial -Force". I got: "Re-scaffolding migration 'Initial'.". But when I typed: "Update-Database" I got this: "Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database."

Comment: Change `Add-Migration` command into `Add-Migration Initial -Force -IgnoreChanges`, then try `Verbose` switch when updating DB: `Update-Database -verbose`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, **PM> Add-Migration Initial -Force -IgnoreChanges** I got **Re-scaffolding migration 'Initial'.** Then **Update-Database -Verbose** I got **..........ClientConnectionId:1ec44fb6-b824-4095-8c87-698af8a6d0ea
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.**

Comment: For `AspNetRoles` table issue after `Update-Database`, check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606160/there-is-already-an-object-named-aspnetusers-in-the-database & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169140/there-is-already-an-object-named-aspnetroles-in-the-database. Note that you may need to comment some relationships-related code lines before adding migration.

Comment: @S.Koshelnyk I have tidied up your question and I hope it now reads correctly. Please [edit] it if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, its ok. Thanks.